# javascript / jquery conditions don't work

Tags: jquery, forms, if-statement, conditional-statements

Please see the code below on jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/j9b0uL6m/3/

```
var message1 = "E-mail has to contain @.";
var message2 = "You have to write your name.";
var message3 = "The password is 123456.";

var mail = $(this).parent().find(".mail").val();
var jmeno = $(this).parent().find(".jmeno").val();
var heslo = $(this).parent().find(".heslo").val();

var hint = "Those errors appeared:";

if (mail.indexOf("@") < 0) {
    hint += "\n\n" + message1;
}
if (jmeno === "") {
    hint += "\n\n" + message2;
}
if (heslo === "123456") {
    hint += "\n\n" + message3;
}
alert(hint);
```

The thing is that for some reason, the alert is showing only if the div contains input with class mail. In other cases it doesn't work. Can you help me?

Comment: you have errors in your console... http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/j9b0uL6m/5/ - in the first set there is to `.mail` element so `mail` will be `undefined` so calling `mail.indexOf("@")` will thrown an error

Comment: If there is no element with the class `mail` then the value `mail`would be undefined and you would call `indexOf` on `undefined`.  In the console you would see a something like `Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined`

Comment: `var mail = $(this).parent().find(".mail").val();`

Comment: @ArunPJohny I've been there, unhappily this solution causes wrong results of conditions. If there's no <input> with a class mail, i don't want to get the same result as if there is empty one.

Comment: @BořekVavřík in that case http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/j9b0uL6m/6/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/j9b0uL6m/7/)

You `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined` because there is no element with class `mail` in the parent element.

so you can use

[**$.trim()**](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.trim/) will return empty string if it is `undefined` or it has only `whitespace` .

```
if ($.trim(mail).indexOf("@") < 0) {\
```

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/h0zzyx1a/)

i modified your code to make it little better

```
var message = []; //array for custom messages 
message['mail'] = "E-mail has to contain @.";
message['jmeno'] = "You have to write your name.";
message['heslo'] = "The password is 123456.";

$(".odkaz").click(function () {
    var hint = []; //hint empty array 
    $(this).parent().find('input').each(function () { //run through each input in the parent element 
        var cls = $(this).attr('class'), //get the class
            inp = $.trim(this.value), //get the value of input and trim it
            ret = Check(cls, inp); //get the return value from the function Check
        if (ret.length) hint.push(ret); //if returned value is not empty add to hint array
    });
    if (hint.length) { //if hind array has length then alert
        alert('Those errors appeared:\n' + hint.join('\n'));
    }
});

function Check(cls, inp) {
    if (cls == 'mail') {
        if (inp.indexOf("@") < 0) {
            return "\n\n" + message['mail'];
        }
    } else if (cls == 'jmeno') {
        if (inp === "") {
            return "\n\n" + message['jmeno'];
        }
    } else if (cls == 'heslo') {
        if (inp === "123456") {
            return "\n\n" + message['heslo'];
        }
    }
    return '';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is because as there is no element with class **mail** the `mail` variable returns **undefined**, so you have to check that if it is not undefined in that case manipulate on it:

```
 if (typeof mail != 'undefined' && mail.indexOf("@") < 0) {
        hint += "\n\n" + message1;
    }
```

if you not check it it will throw error at runtime as it is throwing currently:

> > TypeError: mail is undefined

Answer (score 1):

Well, there occurs an error and so your script isn't executed anymore.

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined

On line 13 (`if (mail.indexOf("@") < 0) {`) you are checking for a "@" without aproving the variable `mail` before.

`mail` should be defined in line 7 (`var mail = $(this).parent().find(".mail").val();`), but if there's no matching element, `mail` will become `undefined`.

Just write in your conditions

```
if ((undefined !== mail) && (YOURCONDITION) {
    // ...
}
```